# firefox can not display some icons of some english sites

Tags: firefox

My firefox now is updated to 26.0.

I find my firefox can not display some icons of some english sites.

Below is my screenshot of wordpress management interface.
On the left of the picture, you can find those strange characters.

What is the matter? Thanks

[image]

Comment: how it was related to ubuntu?

Comment: @AvinashRaj If he runs FF on Ubuntu, then it is related.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Turn off NoScript, or allow the javascripts which should be allowed. Or just allow the fonts for that site.

Or under Firefox->Preferences, under the Content tab click Advanced and check **Allow pages to choose their own font...**

[image: here]

### *Before*

[image: before]

### *After*

[image: after]

Comment: But on windows the icons are displayed normally only using the local fonts, why?